# Redirecionar aplicação no IIS quando o pool está parado

Tags: c#, web.config, redirecionamento-de-url, iis-7

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET C# que é atualizada por outra aplicação no servidor.

Quando inicio o processo de atualização da primeira aplicação na segunda eu paro o pool no qual a primeira está rodando. Nesse momento eu gostaria de habilitar alguma forma de redirecionar a primeira aplicação para uma página na segunda informando que o processo de atualização está acontecendo.

Tentei usando a tag *httpRedirect* no web.config, tentei também usando o arquivo *app_offline.htm* na raiz da primeira aplicação mas em ambos os casos o pool necessita estar ativo para realizar o redirecionamento, o que não é a situação que eu tenho.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu possa realizar o redirecionamento com o pool no IIS parado?

Comment: Além de parar o pool original, você não consegue editar o binding para um pool provisório e ou remapear o site para outro diretório?

Comment: Isso eu não cheguei a tentar, editar o binding vc fala mudar o diretório físico da aplicação?

Comment: Teria que trocar o pool mesmo caso contrário, não importa pra onde você aponte o site ele não iria responder

Comment: O *AppPool* parado retorna um erro 503 quando acessado. Esses erros podem ser tratados, usando uma página específica com uma mensagem amigável, agora se você quiser mesmo redirecionar o site, precisa usar o redirecionador de url, o *URL Rewriter*, pode ler mais aqui sobre como usar: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu acredito que vou ter que fazer isso, deletar a aplicação e criar novamente depois. Tentei colocar algumas regras de redirecionamento segundo a orientação do Ricardo e não deu muito certo, a resposta continua sendo o erro 503.

Comment: Crie no IIS um pool para as atualizações e a aplicação que faz a atualização deve seguir os seguintes passos:
Alterar o pool para o provisório > publicar o app_offline.htm > reiniciar o site > parar o pool original > copiar os arquivos > voltar o o pool original > remover o app_offline.htm > reiniciar o site

Comment: Fiz um teste e acho que essa vai ser a solução mais fácil pra situação que eu tenho, agradeço a rápida ajuda de vocês amigos.